# Find installed version of graphite

Tags: graphite

I have deployed graphite with nginx some time ago, with chef, but didn't froze versions to be installed. Thus now, trying to install with the same recipe i get errors because of missing something related to versions.

I need to find what version of Graphite I have installed on my other CentOS machines, to be able to figure out how to repair recipe.

Thank you.

Gabriel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same issue. I solved it running a `pip list`, which displays every package you installed with pip. You can also run `pip show graphite-web` or `pip show whisper` to get more specific information.

Answer (score 14):

If you have web access to the Graphite installation, you can also see the currently running version under the `/version/` path.

Comment: When I run this I get the wepapp version 1.1.0-dev. Is this the same as the graphite version?

Comment: To get the same information without running graphite I used `find /opt/graphite/ -name "settings\.py" -exec grep -s "WEBAPP_VERSION =" {} \;`